# Python Regex Capture Characters After Whitespace and Hyphen

Tags: python, regex

This should be simple but I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to capture the "-0400" portion of the timestamp shown below.

2020-04-21 23:59:59.999-0400

Any assistance would be appreciated. I know that I need to take a regex crash course.

Comment: The part you want to capture follows _the only_ dot (`.`) in the string and exactly three digits. That's your regex!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll attempt to provide the answer using the `re` library.

I've broken each section into separate lines so you can see what's happening, but you could easily keep it all in a single line.  Adding the `re.X` flag allows for verbose pattern construction.

Basically, I've flagged all the parts of the datetime object and you can use `re.search().group("name of group here")` to pick apart your variable.

```
import re

dt_neg_value = "2020-04-21 23:59:59.999-0400" # Negative UTC
dt_pos_value = "2020-04-21 23:59:59.999+0400" # Positive UTC
dt_london = "2020-04-21 23:59:59.999+00:00" # Zero UTC + colon separator

dt_pat = r"""
    (?P<yr>\d{4})-      # year.  This looks for four numbers.
    (?P<mth>\d{2})-     # month.  This looks for two numbers.
    (?P<dy>\d{2})\s     # day of month.  This looks for two numbers.
    (?P<hh>\d{1,2})     # hour of day.  This looks for one or two numbers.
    :(?P<mm>\d{1,2})    # minute of hour.  This looks for one or two numbers.
    :(?P<nn>\d{1,2})    # second of minute.  This looks for three numbers.
    \.(?P<ms>\d{3})     # millisecond of second.  We have to escape the period so that it doesn't capture a character.
    (?P<utc_off>.?\d+(:\d*)?)  # utc offset. The '-?' part means that a hyphen is optional. This accounts for +/-00:00, as well
    """

# We'll use re.search passing our patter, variable, and the re.X flag.
# Then we can just call out what we want. I've used `utc_off` to indicate UTC offset.

In[0]: re.search(dt_pat, dt_neg_value, re.X).group("utc_off")
Out[0]: '-0400'

In[1]: re.search(dt_pat, dt_pos_value, re.X).group("utc_off")
Out[1]: '+0400'

In[2]: re.search(dt_pat, dt_london, re.X).group("utc_off")
Out[2]: '+00:00'
```

If you're ambitious, you can use `re.findall()` with the same arguments and just pick out what you want by index.

```
In[1]: re.findall(dt_pat, dt_neg_value, re.X)
Out[1]: [('2020', '04', '21', '23', '59', '59', '999', '-0400')]
```

Or, `re.search()` without all the fuss:

```
In[2]: re.search(dt_pat, dt_neg_value, re.X).groups()
Out[2]: ('2020', '04', '21', '23', '59', '59', '999', '-0400')
```

Finally, to keep things in order, try `re.match.groupdict()`

```
In[3]: re.match(dt_pat, dt_neg_value, re.X).groupdict()
Out[3]: {'yr': '2020',
    'mth': '04',
    'dy': '21',
    'hh': '23',
    'mm': '59',
    'nn': '59',
    'ms': '999',
    'utc_off': '-0400'}
```

**EDIT**: Updated to account for negative UTC and inclusion of a colon.

Comment: This answer took a bit of work, +1. When the offset is ahead there will be a `+` instead of the `-`.

Comment: Great point! I updated it to account for that, and also added a snippet for colons.  So, London is at `+00:00`, which this updated pattern should capture.  Same as if it was written `+0000`.

Answer (score 0):

Why regex? Assuming the format of your string is always exactly this, your timezone portion always begins at index 23, so:

```
x = '2020-04-21 23:59:59.999-0400'
print(x[23:])
```

should do.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend working with the `datetime` module since you have a datetime there.
You're looking for the UTC offset so you can use that method, and divide by one hour to get the result in hours.

```
import datetime as dt

s = '2020-04-21 23:59:59.999-0400'
adt = dt.datetime.strptime(s,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z')

adt.utcoffset() / dt.timedelta(hours=1)
-4.0
```

If you like you can wrap that up into a function:

```
def utc_offset_hours(s,strptime_str='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z'): 
    adt = dt.datetime.strptime(s,strptime_str) 
    return adt.utcoffset() / dt.timedelta(hours=1)
```

Example:

```
In [82]: utc_offset_hours('2020-04-21 23:59:59.999-0400')
Out[82]: -4.0
```